# How to execute code after all the handlers for an event finish

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function attached for one event to an element and I need to execute a piece of code after this handler resolve:

```
$("#test").on("change", function() {
    //Do something (e.g. ajax request)
});

$("#test").val('something');
```

I tried to use promises but had no success:

```
$("#test").val('something').promise().done(function(){
    //This didn't work. It needs to be executed after the handler function for the change event finishes
});
```

Comment: So, two things.  If you want some logic to happen after a handler finishes, you'd just stick it at the end of the handler.  Or attach another handler before/after the other one (I forget in which order handlers are executed, but they are executed in an order related to the order they were attached).  Secondly, changing `val()` is not going to create a change event.  If you are expecting that, you will need to explicitly `trigger('change')` or `change()` after changing the value for this logic to happen

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute some code after change event (any handler), then put your code at the end of the handler function:

```
$("#test").on("change", function() {
  //Do something (e.g. ajax request)
  // YOUR CODE
$("#test").val('something');
});
```